# How to escape a prompt with while loop with isNaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So my `while loop` with `isNaN` doesn't work when I type in number in the `prompt`
Here is my code below...

```
var userSalary = prompt("Please type your salary!")

while(isNaN(userSalary)){
    prompt("Please type number!")
}
alert("Good!")
```

Although I input a number, it won't let me escape from the loop...

Comment: It works for me. Can you tell me what value are you entering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign `userSalary` inside of the loop, so the value gets refreshed:

```js
var userSalary = prompt("Please type your salary!")

while(isNaN(userSalary)){
    userSalary = prompt("Please type number!")
}
alert("Good!")
```

Comment: Thank you vary much! I couldn't see the logic flaw, but now when I look back, that makes sense! 

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the statements, and also try a `do..while` loop

```js
var userSalary = prompt('Please type your salary!')
while (isNaN(userSalary = prompt('Please type number!'))) {}
alert('Good!')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting, that is another way to do :)